# Splitting console into different zones

Tags: c, linux

I'm looking for some way of splitting the console into distinct zones, a bit like `screen` does.

The idea is to "freeze" the first X lines, so that they display fixed information, only updated from time to time, while the remaining lines keep working like normal. I've seen this in an application running on an ARM Linux distro, so I believe there should be some way of doing it, without using any fancy stuff, like GTK+.

This should be running on an embedded Linux, so no graphical support, only pure text, and as little external libraries as possible. Can anyone point me at the right direction?

Comment: Use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/); there's a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) about it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to define a scrolling region. If you can assume a compatible terminal this is done with the escape code `ESC [ top ; bottom r`, see http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

Comment: I actually got interested in that. Can anyone else provide me with more links on this subject?

Comment: If you want more verbose descriptions try the vt102 user guide, specifically chapter 5 at http://vt100.net/docs/vt102-ug/chapter5.html (and the whole vt100.net website)

Comment: Thanks for the link. some reading and i see this is sort of what i was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you can make use of the [NCurses library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) to achieve the user experience you describe.

Comment: Not quite what i was looking for, but still a valid option.